# Backtrack installed in VM

Tags: internet-connection

How to connect to the internet in Back Track installed in oracle Virual Box version 3.2.6 r63112.
I have kept the Adapter setting on NAT for Virtual Box
I was trying to connect to internet but it is not working 
Please guide me

Answer (score 0):

1. Is your BT interface up? Usually when starting backtrack the connections are down.

   - Look at the `ifconfing` command, but it should be `ifconfig eth0 up`
2. Does it have an IP? Normally NAT mode of VB provides a DHCP server.

   - Look at dhclient : `dhclient eth0` should work.
3. Then you have to check that the domain name resolver works :

   - Try a `nslookup www.google.com` if the command is available. Look at `/etc/resolv.conf` if it does not work to configure the DNS resolver.
4. Try to connect.

Answer (score 0):

Try running this command from the Terminal

```
/etc/init.d/networking start
```

Since Backtrack is a security suite, no internet connections are enabled by default.